# An authoritative resource for the history of Bitcoin

Tags: history

I've been developing an introductory course on Bitcoin and would like to have a lecture about its history. Other than Wikipedia, does there exist a community-accepted resource elaborating on the history of Bitcoin?

Comment: Charles, I removed your course link because 1) I didn't feel it was relevant to the question, and 2) I feel that you're promoting it too heavily.

Comment: Promoting a course that will eventually become the source for all introductory bitcoin knowledge. I guess so....:(

Comment: Censorship makes me a sad panda. I will be posting a bounty for this question in two days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also found that bitcointalk is one of the best sources, albeit necessary  to wade through a lot of posts. Search there for references to David Chaum, Hal Finney, Nick Szabo, and Wei Dai to understand some of the ideals and ideas that influenced Satoshi.

Here are some other relevant link to get you started:

*[A Timeline History](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/History)

*[A very brief intro](http://bitcoin.org/en/about)

*[The original post of Satoshi on the metzdowd crypto mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09959.html) - Try and follow the whole thread

Google the references in the original paper, will uncover good background detail.

*[Who is Satoshi Nakamoto - you'll need google translate](http://www.bitecoin.com/online/2011/05/57.html)

*[Bitcoin and me (Hal Finney)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=155054.0)

*[The Mystery of the Geneisis Block- very technical](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=172009.0)

Comment: Email me. Id like you to do a guest lecture for my course. Charles.hoskinson@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

The [official Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page) has a page about the [History of Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/History). Also, the original [Bitcoin homepage](http://bitcoin.org/) has a page with [a brief history of Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.org/en/about).

This wiki is primarily maintained by the original creators and developers of Bitcoin.

I especially like

> May 21 2010 - laszlo first to buy pizza with Bitcoins agreeing upon
>   paying 10,000 BTC for ~$25 worth of pizza courtesy of jercos

If you want authority, you can either visit the [Bitcointalk](http://bitcointalk.org) forums and contact [some of the oldest forum members](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=mlist;sort=registered;start=0). Or take a look at the official Bitcoin GitHub project were [the lead developers](https://github.com/bitcoin?tab=members) are listed. (They are also [listed on the Bitcoin homepage](http://bitcoin.org/en/development).)

Comment: DO you have contacts with anyone who was involved with Bitcoin in 2009 or 2010? I'd like to interview them for my class

Comment: You can go to bitcointalk.org, which were the whole bitcoin community came to life. If you list up all accounts sorted by registration date, you can easily find the early birds that helped shape what Bitcoin is today.

Comment: I added some authorative sources to my answer

Answer (score 0):

i think this infographic will help you to get the answer you are looking for. It tells everything about bitcoin history...past...present...future..even also talks about some facts and great incidents that took in this long journey of bitcoin.

I found this infographic at : http://www.2kreviews.com/bitcoin-history-future-infographic/

[image: Bitcoin – An Insight On The Past Events and The Times Ahead [Inforgraphic]]